# How can I keep my cursor normal after exiting a terminal buffer?

Tags: terminal, microsoft-windows, terminal-buffer, cursor

Right now, whenever I open a terminal with `:term`, my cursor changes from a half-height/orange cursor to a full-height/gray cursor (depending on the emulator).

When I navigate back to another window, either via `^W ^W` or an `exit` terminal command, my cursor remains full-height/gray. This is particularly annoying because, in my preferred terminal emulator, this causes the cursor to disappear whenever I place it over a pair of parentheses.

Is there a correct way to exit a terminal window that prevents this from happening? Or maybe a way to disable the cursor changing in the first place?

This messed up cursor persists even once I exit vim, and I haven't been able to find even a control sequence that fixes it (I tried OSC 12 and [these](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/CtrlSeqs#cursor-style), but I couldn't get the underscore modifiers to work).

This is on wsl, tried with built-in and with mintty emulator.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for posting a detailed description of the issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Actually DECSCUSR does work in mintty. E.g. `let &t_EI = "\e[3 q"`

Comment: DECSCUSR worked, the other sequence, `^[[?` _arg_ `c`, didn't work. I couldn't find it documented anywhere else either.